# Is there a DnD5e way to use (small) fighter drones?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, content-identification

I plan on starting a new session of DnD 5e with some friends. Yesterday, I worked out the character with one of the PCs, and he decided he wanted to play a rock gnome.

We came up with the idea of him fighting with little remote controlled drones instead of traditional weapons, so I tried to come up with some mechanics for it. However there might be actual rules I don't know about.

My question is:
*Is there an official set of rules for using remote controlled fighter drones (similar to modern day consumer camera drones) in DnD5e?*

Comment: This is a fine question (also, welcome to the site :) ) , but I want to make sure this is really **all** the information you currently have on the drones before answering; there's a lot of stuff that looks like it's missing and I'm willing to go through and detail what's missing and why it's a problem/how to fill it in, but it would be annoying if you had just neglected to include things in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! The concept was created over a bunch of ciders yesterday evening, so I don't really know anything I might be missing. But if you tell me what you are missing I will add my thoughts to the question.

Comment: Sadly it is - at it is written at the moment - a list of 3 question stacks that incorporate 6 or 7 different ones.

Comment: What kind of action does controlling the drone take? "focus on controlling it" isn't clear, do you mean simply Concentrating is enough? Do they have their normal actions and etc during their turn? I'm going to go ahead and vote to put on hold until it's in its final state. And I agree with Trish, those are 3 very separate questions, I'd suggest opening a separate question for each, but only after the unclear bits are settled.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site doesn't really do back and forth discussion well. If you are looking to work out an idea in progress, e.g. with the expectation that people would point out problems and then you'd fix them and then they'd point out more problems, you may find [a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) a better fit.

Comment: @daze413 How would I go for splitting I feel like that would result in very similar questions? I am not looking for an in depth discussion, I'd rather like to know If my approach contradicts the rules. Would it be appropriate to create a meta post for refining? [There is no sandbox](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/) so would this be a way to improve my question? As for the action part of your comment: Concentrating uses your action, I stated that above.

Comment: You can split the question by asking another one, then linking to the one question that has all the relevant information on it for context.

Comment: @daze413 Sorry, that was unclear. I realize how I can split the question. But I meant content wise. I wanted to know about whether the concept as a whole would fit into the DnD ruleset. Are you saying I should split the concept into different parts, or by what exactly should I split?

Comment: It is a homebrew, of course it does not fit the ruleset. That is the point.

Comment: I was writing a comment to perhaps help reopen this querry (as a few smaller and more approachable questions with solvable problems) but couldn't really think of a way to do so that didn't encourage coming back and re-asking them once the homebrew had been revised (like you may see on a forum). Is there a good Meta on this?

Comment: While the question is too broad for a proper answer, I think it might be helpful to point out that a popular way (and tangentially alluded to in the Equipment section of the Players Guide when discussing custom weapons) to do this sort of thing is to simply make it function mechanically like an existing weapon and only differentiate it cosmetically. So the ranged drone would just be treated as a crossbow, but described as a drone making the attack at the player's direction. Something similar was done in the Force Grey Season 1 stream with the spells of Ashley Johnson's character, Dagny Halvor.

Comment: @cpcodes Thanks for the Idea - I pretty much started with the mechanics of a crossbow and then played around with them until they seemed logical to me (making the ammunition more expensive, changing the skill and so on)

Comment: Are these drones items, creatures or what? What action is required to move a drone? What is drone speed? Can it hover? What action it takes to attack with a drone? What else, if anything, drone can do? What happens if line of sight or line of effect is broken? Does drone occupy space? What space? There's too much things we don't know to evaluate your drones.

Comment: Voting to reopen because I think there's an entirely suitable frame-challenge answer to this.

Comment: @nick012000 “There is a frame challenge” isn’t by itself a good reason to reopen a question. It is quite often the case, as it likely is here, that the reason a frame challenge answer works is *because* the question needs to be closed for one or more reasons.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov In this case, it's "don't bother with homebrew; do this official thing instead". There is a canonical method of achieving the the thing that the OP wants to do.

Comment: It's helpful you added the info on the drones. Still, to me it seems like you have 3 questions here, asking about balance, clarity and RAW? Also "viable" is a concept the DMs will ultimately decide regardless of balance, clarity and general rules.

Comment: [I removed the code formatting](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3087/22566). We don't use that here for a text style due to interoperability with screen reading software.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov and everyone else who votes to reclose: I don't appreciate you immediately voting to close after the vote to reopen took place and closing it while I was asleep, before I could answer it. Please wait 24 hours before doing so in the future. Can someone else vote to reopen please, since I can only do so once? The situation around this question has changed since it was posted four years ago, and there is now an official way to to do this without homebrew.

Comment: @nick012000 That's quite at odds with how closing works. If users believe a question should be closed to prevent answers, they shouldn't wait for others to have a chance of answering. Rather than continuing to push for vote-wars, I'll suggest a meta discussion might be better suited to resolving any problems this question has (to the communities current eyes).

Comment: I reframed the question towards an official rule set, as the community seems to still be interested in answering this

Comment: @T3H40 Asking if there exist official materials for this is fine, but if that is your question, asking for critique of your homebrew content shouldn't be part of the question. As written, this is still too broad, as it asks two entirely different questions in the same post.

Comment: There are two different questions here, each of which has an appropriate scope. The first is about rules (as more splats get published, and more adventures with unique stuff, the more possible stuff someone doesn't know arises) existing to cover this; the second is to assess a homebrew rewiew/balance bit that we have a well established process for.  Please consider splitting this into two questions that link to each other. @ThomasMarkov has observed the same aspects of the question that I note in this comment.

Comment: The questions for review were removed for this exact purpose. I left the mechanics in for reference and historical accuracy. I removed the last sentence so there's no more reference to critique

Comment: As for splitting into two questions (ruleset and critique) I'm not sure that would work, as the question was originally about critique only and then closed, reopened and closed again. I'm not a regular here, so I'm not perfectly sure anymore what's fine and what's not...